# Is there a way to perform arithmetic on integer which has been converted from a string cpp

Tags: c++, string, integer

So basically I am getting two string inputs in the form of coordinates as (x,y) and then I am adding the numbers from the inputted string (which are p1 and p2) to different variables and then adding those variables (which are x1,x2,y1,y2). So is there a way to add the variables together i.e perform arithmetic on the variables, (not concatenate)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string p1, p2;
    cout << "Input x and y cordinates of first point, as (x,y): " << endl;
    cin >> p1;
    string x1, x2, y1, y2;
    for (int i = 0; i < p1.length(); i++) {
        if (p1[i] == ',') {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                x1 += p1[j];
                cout << p1[j];
            }
            cout << endl;
            for (int k = i + 1; k < (p1.length()-1); k++) {
                y1 += p1[k];
                cout << p1[k];
            }
        } 
    }
    cout << "Input x and y cordinates of second point, as (x,y): " << endl;
    cin >> p2;
    for (int i = 0; i < p2.length(); i++) {
        if (p2[i] == ',') {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                x2 += p2[j];
                cout << p2[j];
            }
            cout << endl;
            for (int k = i + 1; k < (p2.length() - 1); k++) {
                y2 += p2[k];
                cout << p2[k];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Adding x1 and x2 gives: " << x1+x2;
    court << "Adding y1 and y2 gives:  << y1+y2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm to lazy to provide full explanation: https://godbolt.org/z/xGd649je6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `std::stoi()`. Add a line to put these `string`s into `int` variables and do your arithmetic:

`int x = stoi(x1);`

Comment: yeah but i cant add using std stoi

Comment: After you convert your `string` variables into `int` variables using `stoi` as indicated above, you can perform any arithmetic operation on the resulting `int`s, including addition, subtraction, whatever you want...

Comment: Yeah yeah sorry I'm an idiot, its working.

Comment: I forgot to add sstream header file